# Filter method time complexity in a TreeSet

Tags: java, algorithm, kotlin, data-structures

```
val x = TreeSet<Int>(compareBy { it.toString() })
x.add(2);
x.add(4)
x.add(5)
x.add(15)
x.add(1)
x.add(34)
println(x)
print(x.filter { it in 5..19 })
```

I have some usecase similar to one metioned as sample code above. I have a bunch of data(size could be pretty huge) consider a timeseries, I need to filter out those items from the list which are between 2 dates? Is there a better solution than O(n) approach?

Comment: @Eran It is Kotlin code. `it` is the implicit parameter in the lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your `TreeSet` is sorted not in the same order as range, so we can't just find range boundaries in `TreeSet` and take all in between.

If `TreeSet` was sorted in natural order (`val x = TreeSet<Int>()`), you could just do:

```kotlin
val subset = x.subSet(5, true, 19, true)
```

This operation is almost free (O(1)), you just pay (O(log(N))) for iterating over this `TreeSet` (iterator construction will require two lookup-s for subset boundaries).

Afterwise, you may sort it in derisered way:

```kotlin
println(subset.toSortedSet(compareBy { it.toString() }))
```